# Can I show admob ads in my app if my app is not exactly legal and not published in PlayStore?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I'm thinking about creating an app where I'll publish free songs and stuff but I don't have the license to do so. So I won't publish it on PlayStore but can I still earn through admob?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Admob even if your app is not being published on Google's Play Store, but You can NOT use Admob if you're app is illegal (using pirated things such as movies/songs)

[reference](https://support.google.com/adsense/forum/AAAAKDuOfxQ9P_g0yxg38s)